# What does it mean to be uniformly distributed on the sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I've only really worked with real-valued random variables. But suppose $X$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. What does it mean for $X$ to be uniformly distributed?

The distribution is just $P(X \in A)$ for $A \subset \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. What does it mean for this to be a uniform distribution? I have a hunch that this means it behaves like the spherical measure $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. But I do not know the formal definition so I'd appreciate someone explaining that to me.

A related question is whether there is only one such uniform measure on the sphere, up to a constant multiple. It feels rather like the question of Haar measure on a locally compact Abelian group, but that's only for translation invariance. Here we're really talking about rotation invariance. That, after all, is what $\sigma$ is all about. Is there such a uniqueness statement for rotationally invariant measures on the sphere, and could one prove that using the uniqueness of Haar measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniform distribution on the sphere means the natural rotationally-invariant probability measure on the sphere.  The sphere $S^{n-1}$ can be considered as the homogeneous manifold $SO(n)/SO(n-1)$, and Haar measure on $SO(n)$ then induces this measure on $S^{n-1}$.